# My login keychain cannot be found. I have Keychain access but no Keychain repair option. OS X El Capitan

Tags: mac, macos, keychain, repair

My login keychain cannot be found.
I have Keychain access but no Keychain repair option in the drop down menu. I am unclear if I have erased something in error, or if this is a common issue?

Answer (score 1):

The login keychain lives in `~/Library/Keychains/`

First thing I'd do is see if Time Machine has a backup.

There is no Repair Keychain function in El Capitan. According to Apple KB: [About the security content of OS X El Capitan 10.11.2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205637)

> Impact: A malicious application may be able to masquerade as the
>   Keychain Server. Description: An issue existed in how Keychain Access
>   interacted with Keychain Agent. This issue was resolved by removing
>   legacy functionality.

According to rumour, it never worked since 10.11 anyway.