# With "Keychain First Aid" apparently removed in 10.11.2 how do i get my keychain fixed?

Tags: keychain

My macbook is presently completely unusable due to an apparently corrupted (?) keychain. As shown in the following question there seems to have been a change in 10.11.2 to have removed the `First Aid`

[My login keychain cannot be found. I have Keychain access but no Keychain repair option. OS X El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235117/my-login-keychain-cannot-be-found-i-have-keychain-access-but-no-keychain-repair)

So then what are my options?  Throw the thing away??  No really - throwing away the keychain and all the passwords is a terrible option. If I have to do .. *that* .. then there better be a way to back up after I lose so much more time on starting the keychain from scratch.

Comment: Time Machine backs up keychains, once an hour/week/month until you run out of disk space.